# How to tell ember to uniquely identify records by another property?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I let ember know that I want it to uniquely find records by the `slug` instead of `id` .

In my route model I can do something like this

```
model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('anime', params.anime_slug);
},
serialize: function(anime) {
    return { anime_slug: anime.get('anime_slug') };
},
```

but whenever I call something like `model.reload()` it tries to reload with the record's id and not the record's slug. So how do I let ember know to uniquely identify the record use `anime_slug` and not `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

**Route:**

```
App.AnimeRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('anime', { anime_slug: params.anime_slug }).then(function(results) { 
      return results.objectAt(0);
    });
  },

  serialize: function(model) {
    return { anime_slug: model.get('anime_slug') };
  },
});
```

Note the change to the model method.

**Router:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('anime', { path: '/anime/:anime_slug' });
});
```

Comment: that'll query the server though, and this method expects multiple records. Even if I return a single record, the issue is then in my controller I have to use ArrayController instead of ObjectController although it should be ObjectController